# how can I find my sentence made by printf in qemu?

Tags: ubuntu, debugging, printf, emulation, qemu

I coded some in qemu source code like error_report() and warn_report() and printf()(these are functions used in qemu to log).

I expected that when I execute qemu, I could see some sentences.
For example, according to 
https://github.com/adava/DECAF-Selective/wiki/QEMU-execution-flow ,
qemu execute some function while running, so if I embeded some code which make sentence(like error_report() above), I could see printed sentences when I execute like
'qemu-system-x86_64 -hda asdf.qcow -m 8192 -enable-kvm 2> ~/qemu.log'

But I could see nothing at the ~/qemu.log where I redirected stderr.
Is there something wrong I have done?

Comment: What source code did you change and how?  This sounds like either the code is not being reached, you are not using the qemu binary with the changes you made, or both.

Comment: @Onofog  sorry for late reply. I solved this problem. I had to disable -enable-kvm option when I execute qemu. I embeded some codes in the function which help guestOS access to DRAM like load instructions. If I use kvm accelerator, maybe it use different path and thats why my intended statements were not appered.